# __udivdi3 undefined — how to find the code that uses it?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

Compiling a kernel module on 32-Bit Linux kernel results in

```
"__udivdi3" [mymodule.ko] undefined!
"__umoddi3" [mymodule.ko] undefined!
```

Everything is fine on 64-bit systems. As far as I know, the reason for this is that 64-bit integer division and modulo are not supported inside a 32-bit Linux kernel.

How can I find the code issuing the 64-bit operations. They are hard to find manually because I cannot easily check if an "/" is 32-bit wide or 64-bit wide. If "normal" functions are undefined, I can grep them, but this is not possible here. Is there another good way to search the references? Some kind of "machine code grep"?

The module consists of some thousand lines of code. I can really not check every line manually.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First, you can do 64 bit division by using the `do_div` macro. (note the prototype is `uint32_t do_div(uint64_t dividend, uint32_t divisor)` and that "`dividend`" may be evaluated multiple times.

```
{
    unsigned long long int x = 6;
    unsigned long int y = 4;
    unsigned long int rem;

    rem = do_div(x, y);
    /* x now contains the result of x/y */
}
```

Additionally, you should be able to either find usage of `long long int` (or `uint64_t`) types in your code, or alternately, you can build your module with the `-g` flag and use `objdump -S` to get a source annotated disassembly.

**note:** this applies to 2.6 kernels, I have not checked usage for anything lower

Comment: to add a tiny bit of information, do_div() is defined in the <asm/div64.h> header.

Comment: It seems rather ridiculous that Linux insists on making you use an ugly function to divide, rather than just implementing `__udivdi3` etc. They're easy to implement, and if you do it in asm, they'll be much more efficient than libgcc's versions (perhaps 2-3 times faster).

Comment: @WilliBallenthin even after using <asm/div64.h> ,face this issue.so anyone suggest me what need to be done to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Hasturkun: How would I use this for a kernel module? Would I run something like make -g ? What am I running objdump on then? Thanks

Comment: @Jordan: The `-g` flag is for GCC (so the object includes debug information) and belongs in `CFLAGS_MODULE`, objdump would be run on the resultant object file.

Comment: @Hasturkun: So for a kernel module, where would I put this? In my kernel module Makefile "CFLAGS_<module>.o := -g" and then objdump on <module>.ko or <module>.o? And then what am I looking for in the output of objdump? I don't see anything about udivdi3, for example. Thanks

Comment: @Jordan: I can't confirm this atm, but IIRC `objdump -Sr` will give you an annotated disassembly with redirections, you should be able to find the call to `__udivdi3` there.

Comment: yes, yes. you have all those utilities for 32 applications, but for 32 bit kernels?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, 64-bit integer divison and modulo *are* supported within a 32-bit Linux kernel; however, you must use the correct macros to do so (which ones depend on your kernel version, since recently new better ones were created IIRC). The macros will do the correct thing in the most efficient way for whichever architecture you are compiling for.

The easiest way to find where they are being used is (as mentioned in @shodanex's answer) to generate the assembly code; IIRC, the way to do so is something like `make directory/module.s` (together with whatever parameters you already have to pass to `make`). The next easiest way is to disassemble the `.o` file (with something like `objdump --disassemble`). Both ways will give you the functions where the calls are being generated (and, if you know how to read assembly, a general idea of where within the function the division is taking place).

Comment: i did try that but objdump uses the "%eiz" register which is not found by gnu as. please help.

Comment: @user135142: `%eiz` is a pseudo index register, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2553556), you can apparently make `as` recognize it by passing `-mindex-reg`.

Answer (score 4):

After compilation stage, you should be able to get some documented assembly, and see were those function are called. Try to mess with CFLAGS and add the -S flags.
Compilation should stop at the assembly stage. You can then grep for the offending function call in the assembly file.