# What is register %eiz?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, objdump

In the following assembly code that I dumped out using `objdump`:

```
lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi
```

What is register `%eiz`? What does the preceding code mean?

Comment: You may find http://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2009-01/msg00081.html interesting.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

See [Why Does GCC LEA EIZ?](http://web.archive.org/web/20090523160558/http://www.blog.bit-blit.org/?p=9):

> Apparently `%eiz` is a pseudo-register that just evaluates to zero at all times (like `r0` on MIPS).

...

> I eventually found a mailing list post by binutils guru Ian Lance Taylor that reveals the answer. Sometimes GCC inserts NOP instructions into the code stream to ensure proper alignment and stuff like that. The NOP instruction takes one byte, so you would think that you could just add as many as needed. But according to Ian Lance Taylor, it’s faster for the chip to execute one long instruction than many short instructions. So rather than inserting seven NOP instructions, they instead use one bizarro LEA, which uses up seven bytes and is semantically equivalent to a NOP.

Comment: Smart People :) Thanks for the answer!
thus the code above is just a longer version of nop :P

Comment: More specifically, it's a placeholder for an unnecessary SIB byte which encodes an addressing mode with no index.

Answer (score 28):

(Very late to the game, but this seemed like an interesting addition): It's not a register at all, it's a quirk of the Intel instruction encoding.  When using a ModRM byte to load from memory, there are 3 bits used for the register field to store 8 possible registers.  But the spot where ESP (the stack pointer) "would" be is instead interpreted by the processor as "a SIB byte follows this instruction" (i.e. it's an extended addressing mode, not a reference to ESP).  For reasons known only to the authors, the GNU assembler has always represented this "zero where a register would otherwise be" as a "%eiz" register.  The Intel syntax just drops it.

Comment: binutils only does this for *redundant* SIB bytes (i.e. base other than E/RSP, and no index).  It uses `(%esp)` / `(%rsp)` instead of `(%esp, %eiz, 1)`.

Comment: Is this suitable input for the GNU assembler, or is it only a disassembler feature?

Comment: the mentioned reasons are probably that IZ stands for index zero.

Answer (score 16):

Andy Ross provides a lot more of the underlying reasoning, but is unfortunately wrong or at the very least confusing about the technical details. It is true that an effective address of just `(%esp)` cannot be encoded with just the ModR/M byte as instead of being decoded as `(%esp)`, it is used to signal that a SIB byte is also included. However, the `%eiz` pseudo-register is not always used with a SIB byte to represent that a SIB byte was used.

The SIB byte (scale/index/base) has three pieces to it: the index (a register such as as `%eax` or `%ecx` that the scale is applied to), the scale (a power of two from 1 to 8 that the index register is multiplied by), and the base (another register that is added to the scaled index). This is what allows for instructions such as `add %al,(%ebx,%ecx,2)` (machine code: `00 04 4b` -- opcode, modr/m, sib (note no %eiz register even though the SIB byte was used)) (or in Intel syntax, "add BYTE PTR [ecx*2+ebx], al").

However, `%esp` cannot be used as the index register in a SIB byte. Instead of allowing this option, Intel instead adds an option to use the base register as is with no scaling or indexing. Therefore to disambiguate between the case of `add %al,(%ecx)` (machine code: `00 01` -- opcode, modr/m) and `add %al,(%ecx)` (machine code: `00 04 21` -- opcode, modr/m, sib), the alternate syntax `add %al,(%ecx,%eiz,1)` is instead used (or for Intel syntax: `add BYTE PTR [ecx+eiz*1],al`).

And as explained in the article linked to by Sinan, this specific instruction (`lea 0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi`) is merely used as a multi-byte nop (equivalent to `esi = &*esi`) so that only one nop-like instruction has to be executed instead of multiple nop instructions.

Comment: BTW, the reason ESP can't be an index is that `(%esp)` is a much more useful addressing mode than `(%esp, %esp, 1..8)`.  Since you can't encode base=ESP without a SIB byte, you need some way to specify no index.  (Because no base would require a disp32, and they didn't want to require `disp32=0( , %esp, 1)` to make ESP-relative addressing unreasonably expensive.)