# Omission of base register in x86 AT&T addressing mode

Tags: assembly, x86, att, addressing-mode

I am trying to decode the syntax of the intel IA32 x86 cmp command.

The command in question is

```
cmp 0x804a38(,%ebx,4), %eax
```

I have a rough estimate of whats going on - the (content of `ebx *4`) + `0x0804a38` is then subtracted from `eax` and the condition codes then set.

However, I know I am wrong because the jump command after that isn't executed - its je

What am I doing wrong here? is it because the cmp is missing an argument?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It is the contents of (0x804a38 + ebx * 4) that you are comparing to eax, right?  Your statement of it is ambiguous.

Comment: From the wording of your question it sounds like you completely missed the fact, that the first argument is memory reference, i.e. `0x80...+ebx*4` is calculated as memory address, and then 4 byte value is loaded from that memory address, and compared with `eax`. In Intel syntax the instruction would look like this: `cmp eax,[ebx*4+0x804a38]` (in Intel syntax memory reference is in square brackets, not ordinary parentheses, and the syntax is relaxed, i.e. `[0x804a38+ebx*4] == [ebx*4+0x804a38]`, most of the assemblers will even evaluate simple expression for you, like `[ebx*4+label+15]`.

Answer (score 3):

It is allowed to omit a base register in the SIB (scale-index-base) notation of Intel x86 machine instructions.

From the [Intel SDM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm#combined), volume 2, table 2-3:

[image: SIB table]

The highlighted row, column, value and the comment below the table designate the corresponding SIB byte value.

> However, I know I am wrong because the jump command after that isn't executed

The `cmp` instruction is encoded correctly by itself. It is something that is wrong elsewhere: either with its memory argument that cause a fault, the following `je` instruction (which you did not show), or you just misinterpreted the results of your code execution.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the `je` doesn't jump, and falls through?  That means it executed but found the condition was false.  That happens when the 4 bytes in memory don't match the 4 bytes in EAX, so `cmp` won't set ZF.

The only way for `je` to not *execute* would be if `cmp` caused a segmentation fault or something, so the program died before reaching the instruction after `cmp`.

And yes, you are decoding the AT&T addressing-mode syntax correctly, it's a scaled-index with no base register, just a `disp32`.)  `cmp` isn't missing an argument, the addressing mode is missing a base (which is totally normal).  **`%ebx` is being used as a scaled index into a static array of dwords**.

[Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes/34058400#34058400).  (I'm not sure if there's a good link for AT&T syntax addressing modes, but what the machine can encode is fixed; AT&T and Intel syntax can both express every addressing mode the machine can do.)

Comment: I remember that at least some time ago (~2009) GNU's toolchain used `eiz` at a missing base: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553517/what-is-register-eiz

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov: In my experience, it only uses that as a placeholder for a missing *index* in an addressing mode that does use a SIB byte, but not for `base=%esp` with no index where a SIB byte is still mandatory.  i.e. to tell you that the addressing-mode is padded when it didn't need to be, like as part of a long NOP.

Comment: oops, indeed, not *base* but *index*! Thanks

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov: also, I just checked and GAS doesn't accept `mov (%ebx, %eiz, 4), %eax`  as *input*.  The OP's code is probably disassembly output anyway (given the numeric displacement), but I thought it was interesting that `%eiz` (/ `%riz`?) was an output-only thing for binutils.

Comment: @PeterCordes This whole `eiz` thing is super weird, too.  No idea why they did it.

Comment: @fuz: I think so the disassembler can be more "accurate" and show you when there's a SIB, even in Intel syntax, e.g. `db 0x8b, 0x4, 0x21` -> nasm -> `objdump -drwC -Mintel` -> `mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rcx+riz*1]`.  Normally only happens in long-NOPs, where it's nice to see what the padding is.   They also include an explicit zero when there is one (like for `base=ebp`), you get `0+` or `0(%rbp)`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, but `(%eax,,1)` is already explicit enough.  No idea why an extra `%eiz` is needed.

Comment: @fuz: For Intel syntax, where there's no way to indicate an empty index otherwise.  They could have made that an Intel-only thing, but maybe it was easier not to.