# What register is riz?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, disassembly, objdump, addressing-mode

I was disassembling a program and I don't understand what "riz" means here.
I don't know of a register with this name.

or     cl,BYTE PTR [rcx+riz*2+0x65]

Can someone explain it to me?
Thanks

Comment: It's how your disassembler indicates an unnecessary SIB byte that doesn't actually code for an index.  Related: [What methods can be used to efficiently extend instruction length on modern x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48046814) mentions it.  Ah, there's a whole Q&A about it for 32-bit address-size:  [What is register %eiz?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2553517)