# Determine location of linker error (udivdi3, divdi3)

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linker, linker-errors

I'm trying to compile my driver in a 32 bit version of the Linux kernel, and I'm getting linker errors due to not properly calling the correct functions to do 64-bit division. The problem is that I have no idea where to look for these. Is there any effective way to find the location or at least the file which is causing the errors?

```
ERROR: "__udivdi3" [driver.ko] undefined!
ERROR: "__divdi3" [driver.ko] undefined!
```

Edit: [__udivdi3 undefined — how to find the code that uses it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063585/udivdi3-undefined-howto-find-code) didn't really answer the question, or I don't quite understand how to do it. Does anyone have any suggestions? I was attempting to use LD_DEBUG, but I'm not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: Ah yes, might be. Thanks

Comment: Can you use `nm` to find the object files that contain the references?  Or the programs like `objdump`?

Comment: Yep, objdump works. See discussion in other thread. Thanks!